Laravel 10: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashboardController] does not exist
I tried logging in a user (email and password) to the user's dashboard page but got the error message:
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashboardController] does not exist, after clicking the login button.
My expectations:
After a user has logged in and is authenticated the user is to be redirected to the dashboard page.
But instead I get  this error:
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashboardController] does not exist.
Look at the full description of what I’ve done:
I’ve written this code:
<x-layout.guest-layout>
        <form action="{{route('login.func')}}" method="post">

        @csrf

        <main class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-3 py-4">

            <div>
                <h4>Login</h4>
            </div>

            @if (Session('success'))
                <p class="text-green-500 font-bold p-2 flex flex-row justify-center item-center">
                    {{Session('success')}}
                </p>
            @endif
            
            @if (Session('error'))
                <p class="text-red-500 font-bold p-2 flex flex-row justify-center item-center">
                    {{Session('error')}}
                </p>
            @endif
            
            @if (Session('exist'))
                <p class="text-gray40 font-bold p-2 flex flex-row justify-center item-center">
                    {{Session('exist')}}
                </p>
            @endif

            <div class="flex flex-col justify-start w-1/2">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="rounded-md p-1 border focus:outline-green-500" type="email" name="email" id="email">

                {{-- error directives --}}
                @error('email')
                    <div class="font-semibold text-red-500 text-sm">
                        {{$message}}
                    </div>
                @enderror
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="flex flex-col justify-start w-1/2">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="rounded-md p-1 border focus:outline-green-500" type="password" name="password" id="password">

                @error('password')
                    <div class="font-semibold text-red-500 text-sm">
                        {{$message}}
                    </div>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="flex flex-col gap-2 w-1/2">
                <button class="text-white bg-green-500 font-bold rounded-md p-1">Login</button>
                <a href="/register" class="text-green-400 font-semibold">Create an Account</a>
            </div>
            
        </main>
    </form>
</x-layout.guest-layout>

within this file below:
Login page file location
that allows users to login, sending their credentials to be authenticated,  into the file below:
Location of authentication controller file
which gets handled by the loginFunc method below:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\app\auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\UserModel;
use App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class authController extends Controller
{
    public function loginPage(){
        if (Session::get('userID')) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        
        return view("app.pages.auth.loginPage");
 
    }

    public function registerPage(){
        if (Session::get('userID')) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        return view("app.pages.auth.registerPage");
    }

    // public function dashboardPage(){
    //     if (!Session::get('userID')) {
    //         return Back()->with('', 'Access Denied');
    //     }
    //     return view('app.pages.dashboard.protectedDashPage');
    // }

    public function loginFunc(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'email' => ['required', 'email'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:15']
            ]);

            $existingUser = UserModel::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            if (!$existingUser /**$exitingUser->password !== $request->password*/) {
                return redirect('/')->with('exist', 'User does not exist');
            }elseif(!Hash::check($request->password, $existingUser->password)){
                return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Invalid email or password');
            }

            $request->session()->start();
            $request->session()->put('userID', $existingUser->id);
            return redirect('/dashboard');

        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            return back()->withErrors($e->validator->errors());
        }//;
    }

using this route:
// Route to controller that processes form's input
Route::post('/login', [authController::class, 'loginFunc'])->name('login.func');

The loginFun authenticates the user, and if the user is authenticated, redirects the user to the dashboard page file:
location of dasboard bage file
Using the the last route in the code below:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\app\auth\authController;
use App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;



// Route to pages
Route::get('/', [authController::class, 'loginPage'])->name('index.page');
Route::get('/register', [authController::class, 'registerPage'])->name('register.page');
Route::get('/about', [dashController::class, 'aboutPage'])->name('about.page');


Route::middleware('authM')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard',[dashController::class, 'dashboardPage'])->name('dashboard.page');
});

route to dashboard page file
This route points to two files. First the authM middleware file below:
Location of authM middleware file
Having the code below:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class authM
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (!Session::get("userID")) {
            return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Please Login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}


That prevents any unauthorise ascess to the dashboard page, and the dashController contoller file below:
Loction of the dashboard controller file
That contains the dashboardPage method below:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class dashController extends Controller
{
    public function aboutPage()
    {
        return view('app.pages.dashboard.about');
    }
    
    public function dashboardPage(){
        return view('app.pages.dashboard.protectedDashPage');
    }
}


Which renders the dashboard page (protectedDashPage.blade.php).
But I just keep getting the error:
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashboardController] does not exist.
error message

Your error is Target class [App\Http\Controllers\app\dashboard\dashboardController] does not exist But your controller name is dashController. Check for any naming convention issue.Also clear the cache php artisan cache:clear.

I've done all that, but it still won't work. It keeps giving me the same error with the wrong controller name. Don't know what to do.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Oh, ok. I would avoid doing that next time. @pierpy
